# Superscripts on a `\widetilde`

Tags: superscripts, mathematics

Consider the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    KO^n(X), \widetilde{KO}^n(X).
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: result]

The superscript appears too high in the second one. Ideally, I'd have the `n` appear at the same height as in the first case, but without having the tilde covering it. Any ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
    KO^n(X), \widetilde{KO}{}^n(X)., \widetilde{KO}^n(X).
\]
\end{document}
```